# How do I ask a question about the effects that a modifier will have on geometry without answers being "opinion based"?

Tags: discussion

How do I modify a question that asks about the effects of applying modifiers so that the answer will be "fact" based rather than "opinion" based.

I'm uncertain how a question that asks what effect something has isn't fact based when it's an observable and repeatable process.

Answer (score 1):

To make any question objective and based on facts give a us specific use case, with an objective scenario and an concrete example.

If necessary illustrate it with images and state your end goal.

Also avoid phrasing questions with "*Whats the best (...)?*", "*Should I (...)?*" or "*How would you (...)?*".

Preferred phrasing is "*For specific purpose X would A or B give more adequate results?*" or "*What are the advantages or disadvantages of method A versus method B?*"

Comment: I tried that, solidifying a model for 3D printing, or creating a prop with no moving parts. Both create fixed geometry in accordance with an algorithm. But for reasons that I don't fully understand this is considered opinion rather than fact even though it's a machine doing it. I think that maybe somebody is using a bot to do edits rather than doing it manually, and it's just picking up on key words. I've had this before a couple of times.

Comment: Looking back at your question queue there seems to be a history of vague questions without any specific examples or concrete end goals. Quoting JeffUK in https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/240845 "*I don't think there is a specific answer to this question, it depends on the model* (...)" or see my comment at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/241349 .

Comment: Since no further details have been provided in the meantime your questions remain on hold until more details allow answering objectively. You can always edit your posts to get them reopened, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions and https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions

Comment: This is typical, even when I ask for guidance on how to modify a question all I get is the same vague non-answers. How much clearers can "for 3D printing" be, do I need to specify the exact model of 3D printer?

Comment: @AaarghZombies In cases like this, it always helps to provide a specific example you have in mind that is representative of the problem you're trying to solve. This helps to get specific answers.

Comment: @AaarghZombies: Although i also don't like if questions are closed too quickly i have to admit that your question doesn't have much information at all. They don't ask only for the model of the printer but for the model/character/thing you want to print. And you just referring here to the model of the printer. So try to answer or make clear what you mean (just because it is obvious for you does not mean it is obvious for everybody else) and if you got comments like this (from those who want to help you) you should answer them or improve/edit your question.

Comment: @AaarghZombies: and asking " what is the most effective order" is opinion based. Why? because everybody has a different knowledge level. If a guy is e.g. familiar with animation nodes an animation nodes solution with 3 nodes would need 1 minute for that. If you never heard of animation nodes you might already fail just to install animation nodes....

Comment: @Chris. There are objective standards by which topology can be judged, so by definition it's not opinion based unless you specifically ask for it to be.